# Nhibernate QueryOver helper for date range without passing field name

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda, expression, queryover

I have custom DateRange class and want to simplify adding new critera for QueryOver, by creating new helper method and passing lambda which contains the field I need and a date range. But I can't understand how to transfer and transform expression.

```
public static IQueryOver<tRoot, tSubType> AddDateRangeCritery<tRoot,tSubType>(this IQueryOver<tRoot, tSubType> query,
                         System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<tSubType, object>> expr, DatesRange range)
    {
        if (range?.minDate != null)
            query.Where(??? >= range.minDate.Value);
    }
```

I tried compile expression, but I feel it's not best idea + can't understand how to get passed to expression params. Is it possible to make this without ICriterion? Don't want to go this way because we can pass property and not field name, which more stable design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change a little the signature of the method it becomes quite easy:

```
public static IQueryOver<tRoot, tSubType> AddDateRangeCritery<tRoot, tSubType>(
    this IQueryOver<tRoot, tSubType> query,
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<tSubType, DateTime>> expr,
    DatesRange range)
{
    if (range?.minDate != null)
    {
        var propr = expr.Body;
        var value = Expression.Constant(range.minDate.Value);
        var cmp = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propr, value);
        var expr2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<tSubType, bool>>(cmp, expr.Parameters);
        query.Where(expr2);
    }

    return query;
}
```

I've changed the expression to `Func<tSubType, DateTime>`. If you really need it to be `, object` then it becomes two or three lines more of code.

Comment: Thx! This works. My bad, I did not know how to work with expressions, and pass params from expression input.